Let $F \supset K \supset L$ be fields with orders less than 100 and do not include an element $x\neq 1$ that $x^5=1$. Find the order of $F$.
Let $F \supset K \supset L$ be fields with order less than 100 and do not include an element $x\neq 1$ that $x^5=1$. Find the order of $F$.
my attempt
I used the Tower Law where we have
$
[F:L]=[F:K][K:L]
$
Since the fields $F$, $K$, and $L$ are not equal, each of the indices must be greater or equal to 2. So if $|L|=x$, $|F|\ge x^4$. The possible candidates are 16 and 81. However, since $F*$ should be a cyclic group of order $|F|-1$, by the condition we have, none of these answers are available as they must admit an element $x$ which has an order 5.

@RHspqr: no, $\mathbb{F}_4$ is not contained in $\mathbb{F}_8$. The issue is that the OP assumes that $|F|$ must equal some $x^4$. But why is that?

@Aphelli Yes you are right

As @Aphelli said, perhaps $\mathbb{F}_{64}$ is still a suitable choice

Let $p$ be the characteristic of the field. Then $|F|=p^n$ for some $n$. An argument similar to yours shows that $n\geq4$. Note that we only have the two possibilities $2$ or $3$ for $p$, as already $5^4>100$.
Recall that $F^\times$ is cyclic and we have an element such that $x^5=1$ if and only if $5$ divides $|F^\times|=p^n-1$. For $p=3$ and $n=4$, $p^n-1=80$ which is divisible by $5$. Also note that if $p=3$ and $n>4$ then $p^n>100$ so our only option is $p=2$.
By your reasoning $n$ always has to have at least two factors. So we have to check $n=4,6,8,9,...$. $n=8$ already makes $p^n$ too large and $5$ divides $2^4-1$. We thus have $p=2$ and $n=6$ making $|F|=2^6=64$. And indeed $5$ does not divide $64-1$.
